# Match record selection in subreport to parent record

Tags: crystal-reports

My billing system produces an invoice with product details. Inside the description of each product there is a serial number.

On the second page, a subreport lists all the serial numbers for the client of the invoice. I need this subreport to only use the serial numbers contained in the parent products description. How can I accomplish this?

I have tried using a similar formula in the subreport, which seems to work but shows the same serial number many times. (The product list can be listed many times the same product with same serial number.) I think I need a group-by function but I wouldn't know where to put it.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by using the previous function in the *Suppress (No Drill Down)* section.